# Clarify difference between hook_form_TYPE_alter and hook_form_TYPE_EDIT_alter

Tags: hooks

I have a site with a lot of hook form alters for node forms and I'm finding that I have to create two separate hook functions to affect **both** the node create and node edit forms.

For example, I have to put both:

```
module_events_form_node_event_form_alter()
```

and

```
module_events_form_node_event_edit_form_alter()
```

With the same functionality in both functions so that it covers both new and edited nodes. Is there a way to have one hook_form_alter() to cover both form conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the full form ID with content type and operation or the base form ID `node_form`. This is without the operation but also missing the content type. So when you alter the base form you have to check for a specific content type if you don't want to alter all node forms:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  if ($node->getType() == 'event') {
    // change the node form for the content type event and any operation
  }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, if I user form ID with content type then I must use two functions to account both new and edit forms but if I just use hook_form_alter and check for the type then I don't, correct?

Comment: The FORM_ID contains both content type + operation (create is default and default is omitted). The BASE_FORM_ID I've suggested contains neither of them and you can check them individually. BTW if you need the operation use `$form_state->getFormObject()->getOperation()`.